# Replace dataframe header with lines of string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
                   X             Y          Z     Value
0       6.196133e+06  2.321880e+06   1356.439      0.01
1       6.196155e+06  2.321867e+06   1347.363      0.01
2       6.196176e+06  2.321854e+06   1338.229      0.01
3       6.196197e+06  2.321841e+06   1332.272      0.01
4       6.196218e+06  2.321828e+06   1326.691      0.01
```

How can I write the data to a .csv (or .txt) file without row indices, so that the columns are tab (or space) delimited, and the header is displayed as follows:

```
title = "dataset test"
variables = "X", "Y", "Z", "Value"
zone t = "Data Field",i = 134, j = 293, k = 5, f=point
6.196133e+06  2.321880e+06   1356.439      0.01
6.196155e+06  2.321867e+06   1347.363      0.01
6.196176e+06  2.321854e+06   1338.229      0.01
6.196197e+06  2.321841e+06   1332.272      0.01
6.196218e+06  2.321828e+06   1326.691      0.01
```

FYI: The header is Tecplot software header.

Comment: write in line ?

Comment: Where do the i, j and k values come from?

Comment: The header is user defined. i, j, k, and strings like "Data Field" or "dataset test" are all user defined.

Comment: I can glue the header lines parameters (i,j,k, and strings in " ") in advance based on other data. In fact I want just paste these three lines on top of my output files followed by tab  (or space) separated data from dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare your inputs:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir('Directory to save to')

df = pd.DataFrame([[6.196133e+06,2.321880e+06,1356.439,0.01],
                    [6.196155e+06,2.321867e+06,1347.363,0.01],
                    [6.196176e+06,2.321854e+06,1338.229,0.01],
                    [6.196197e+06,2.321841e+06,1332.272,0.01],
                    [6.196218e+06,2.321828e+06,1326.691,0.01]],columns = ['X','Y','Z','Value'])

info = pd.DataFrame([['title = "dataset test"'],
                    ['variables = ' + str(df.columns.tolist())],
                    ['zone t = "Data Field", i = 134, j = 293, k = 5, f=point']])
```

To save to Excel file:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

info.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Output', header=None, index=False, startcol=0,startrow=0)
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Output', header=None, index=False, startcol=0,startrow=3)

writer.save()
```

To save to CSV file:

```
with open('out.csv', 'w') as myfile:
    info.to_csv(myfile, header=None, index=False, sep=' ')
    df.to_csv(myfile, header=None, index=False, sep=' ')
```

Comment: This works for the most part except the output is excel. There are scripts to read excel and write them to csv/txt but my files are big and many. Moreover I am afraid going back and forth mess up the file format and encoding which I want to avoid as well. thanks for the solution though.

Comment: I have added an option to save to CSV, sorry for missing that in your original question.

Comment: Thanks this works the way that I want it. But it write the header with extra " and []: `"title = ""dataset test"""
"variables = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Value']"
"zone t = ""Data Field"", i = 134, j = 293, k = 5, f=point"`

Comment: Not a problem @Bob!

Comment: it write the header with extra " and []: "title = ""dataset test""" "variables = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Value']" "zone t = ""Data Field"", i = 134, j = 293, k = 5, f=point". Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You can remove those when you specify the info DataFrame, just pass them in as strings using str()

Answer (score 1):

(I haven't tested this personally, so there may need some tweaks ;-)) 
According to the Panda docs, something like this should work: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-store-in-csv

```
filename = 'output.csv'
with open(filename, 'w') as fid:
    # write the Tecplot header
    fid.write('title = "dataset test"')
    fid.write('variables = [{0}]'.format(df.columns))
    fid.write('zone t = "Data Field",i = 134, j = 293, k = 5, f=point')
# write the data
df.to_csv(filename, '\t', columns=df.columns, header=False, index=False, mode='w+')
```

Comment: solution gives this error: `'file' object has no attribute 'writeline'`.

Comment: It doesn't write the header and messes up the file format as well. Thanks for the try though.